# Unknown port - Looking for a VGA converter

Tags: macbook-pro, vga

I have the following plug-in hole to put a converter to plug it to a VGA screen.

[image]

Issue is I've never seen such type of plug-in.

Does anyone know about it, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a white MacBook Core Duo 13-inch, and while I have not seen one of those for a while (*congrats on keeping it running!*) I believe that is what is called a mini-DVI port.

So a search for mini-DVI to VGA should find you the adapter you are looking for. I doulbt Apple still carries it and you might have to buy a used adapter (ebay and the like) but that is the spec.

BTW, in the future when asking for help on something it is best to give the model number, part number or official designation of the hardware (if applicable) and/or the version of macOS on the Mac, also if applicable. You are more likely to get an accurate response, and a faster one.

Comment: Hi @steve-chambers, thank you for your help. Long story short, a friend of mine gave it to me, replacing the old MacOS with an ubuntu. He scrapped it from his work so I have no idea of the model... :)

Comment: I *think* on those there was a label on the bottom, but with Linux on it it would be hard to find the model number via software

Comment: Lemme have a look @steve-chambers. It will be good to know for the next time